# Send Multi Notification to GCM using JSON

Tags: android, json, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send multiple notifications to many registered devices at once using GCM, and I know that that can not be done using the plain text since it only can be used to send notification for one device at time. So instead I decided to make the HTTP body content using JSON and I managed to make the following string that represents the JSON object:

```
{ collapse_key : my_CollapseKey, data.message : myMessage,  registration_ids : ["regid1","regid2",...] }
```

But whenever I send the request I get a 400 response which states Bad Request, and when I refer to the document of [GCM Architectural Overview](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) it states that

> Response 400 Only applies for JSON requests. Indicates that the request could not be parsed as JSON, or it contained invalid fields (for instance, passing a string where a number was expected)

Here is the snapshot from my web app developed in ASP.Net that I used to send the request:

```
request.ContentType = "application/json"
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization: key=My_Server_Key")
        request.Headers.Add("Sender: id=myProject_ID")
        Dim collapsKey = Guid.NewGuid.ToString("n")
        Dim data As String = "{ collapse_key : " + collapsKey + "," + " data.message : " + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text) + "}" + ", registration_ids : " + jsonids1 + "}"
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
```

Any idea how I can parse my JSON object correctly and send multiple notifications?
any help will be completely appreciated.

regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSON should look like this :

```
{
  "registration_ids" : ["APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",...],
  "data" : {
    "Team" : "Portugal",
    "Score" : "3",
    "Player" : "Varela",
  },
}
```

You forgot to create a dictionary for the data.

From GCM documentation :

> **data**
>   A JSON object whose fields represents the key-value pairs of the message's payload data. If present, the payload data it will be
>   included in the Intent as application data, with the key being the
>   extra's name. For instance, "data":{"score":"3x1"} would result in an
>   intent extra named score whose value is the string 3x1. There is no
>   limit on the number of key/value pairs, though there is a limit on the
>   total size of the message (4kb). The values could be any JSON object,
>   but we recommend using strings, since the values will be converted to
>   strings in the GCM server anyway. If you want to include objects or
>   other non-string data types (such as integers or booleans), you have
>   to do the conversion to string yourself. Also note that the key cannot
>   be a reserved word (from or any word starting with google.). To
>   complicate things slightly, there are some reserved words (such as
>   collapse_key) that are technically allowed in payload data. However,
>   if the request also contains the word, the value in the request will
>   overwrite the value in the payload data. Hence using words that are
>   defined as field names in this table is not recommended, even in cases
>   where they are technically allowed. Optional.

Comment: IS IT registration_id or registration_ids since I want to make multi sending here

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it to registration_ids.

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested but did not work, and I really did not got your point in creating a dictionary for data

Comment: I mean that instead of putting `data.message : myMessage` in your JSON, you should put `"data" : {"message" : "myMessage"}`. That would make the value of the data key a dictionary. That's how the GCM documentation says it should be - http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html.

Comment: {registration_ids:["APA91bGzn_0QP_hWt7f-whQKkAJ4-iuGlRfQqA_sWcjvOZZ3v-5y5PSNFEPrD-siR5WSyskTVaBST5LHDsIFCTZqY_-ectSPDBUeJGstmabKSLkcoNuJb5CngeQ__3NCwRdrXF3WKkirMbE-TdHABDyRFGgJEJK-dQ",".....","...."],data:{message:Wlecome to the app,},collapse_key:wlecome_message,} this my json object and in response I got nothing like word nothing

Comment: You should use quotes for all the Strings within the JSON, so it should be : `{"registration_ids":["APA91bGzn_0QP_hWt7f-whQKkAJ4-iuGlRfQqA_sWcjvOZZ3v-5y5PSNFEPr‌​D-siR5WSyskTVaBST5LHDsIFCTZqY_-ectSPDBUeJGstmabKSLkcoNuJb5CngeQ__3NCwRdrXF3WKkirMb‌​E-TdHABDyRFGgJEJK-dQ",".....","...."],"data":{"message":"Wlecome to the app",},"collapse_key":"wlecome_message",}`

Comment: Thanks alot Eran for your contributions which without it I will be stoke in this for ever, I really did not think that I need to quote string. Really thanks